# How to log the time an external data connection/query refreshes?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an external data query in Excel connected to a Microsoft Access database that I refresh once a day to populate a table in Excel, and I want to measure exactly how long it takes to refresh the query/connection.

I believe I am close with a solution for this using VBA on the worksheet and the TableUpdate selection there? But can't seem to get anything to actually work with this.

FYI, I am doing this as with some recent Excel updates, a couple of my queries have started to take double the time, and so I am wanting to revert back to old Excels and then measure how long it takes to refresh, and as it takes up to 15 minutes, I can't be sitting there watching it, and record the time, but I will click refresh, do something else for 20 mins, and find out when it's finished refreshing.

Comment: *I believe I am close with a solution for this using VBA on the worksheet and the TableUpdate selection there* - please post the code you have currently implemented and tell us where it's failing.

Comment: If you have a query that takes more than 10 seconds to return with results (after connecting), either the query is poorly written, selects too many columns from too many tables, joins aren't made through primary/foreign keys, keys are composite and non-numeric, the schema is missing indexes, or a combination of the above.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I've only done this:
Private Sub Worksheet_TableUpdate(ByVal Target As TableObject)
Range("A1").Value = Now()
End Sub

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Well it is a pretty massive query working off some very big data sets within Access (multiple joins on at least three big datasets). And Access is very limited, so I'm not sure I can do much more on the 'query' optimisation in Access.

Comment: Do they run in >10 minutes *in Access*? My point is, you should be looking for ways to optimize your schema for querying, instead of ways to document how bad it actually is. Relational databases are literally made for this, and they're very good at it. Access does have some limitations, but if your schema involves composite string keys, partial and/or conditional joins, and you're selecting from a view that's selecting from a view that's selecting from a view, the problem isn't Access.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a "custom" timed query table using a class and event sinking, like so.

A class called clsTimedQueryTable, with the following code

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents qtTimed As QueryTable
Private tmStart As Date
Private tmEnd As Date

Public Property Get RefreshTimeTaken() As Variant
    RefreshTimeTaken = DateDiff("m", tmStart, tmEnd)
    Debug.Print RefreshTimeTaken
End Property

Public Sub INIT(qtToTime As QueryTable)
    Set qtTimed = qtToTime
End Sub
Private Sub qtTimed_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    tmEnd = Now
    Module1.TimeTaken = RefreshTimeTaken
    Debug.Print "Ended : " & tmEnd
End Sub

Private Sub qtTimed_BeforeRefresh(Cancel As Boolean)
    tmStart = Now
    Debug.Print "Started : " & tmStart
End Sub
```

Then in a normal module have the following

```
Private clsQueryTable As clsTimedQueryTable
Public TimeTaken As Double

Private Sub SetUp()
    Set clsQueryTable = New clsTimedQueryTable
    clsQueryTable.INIT ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).QueryTable
End Sub
```

Refreshing the table will now handle the timings and pass the result back to TimeTaken.  There is no need to do the way I have to put the variable in, it's from the class property also.

I would also add a function `.RefreshTable` in the class too, to control it all from the class, rather than set class, right click refresh, etc.

Up to you.

Comment: Thanks for this, but this is very complicated. I was expecting something a lot more simple, given there is the TableUpdate function available?

Comment: Where is the tableupdate function?  Does it have the opportunity to time the start and end or just when it's updated?